# (Excel) Multiple column lookup with partial match to count matching cells

Tags: excel

In sheet 1, column A contains problem descriptions (e.g. A1: Black screen on PC, A2: Faulty Drive etc).
Column B contains the PC brand/model name (e.g. B1: Dell DX300, B2:Dell DX400, B3: HP Pro100).

```
***Problem  (Col A)   -       Brand / Model (Col B)***    
Black Screen          -         DELL DX300    
Faulty Drive          -         DELL DX400    
Not booting           -         HP PRO100    
Black Screen          -         DELL DX300    
Black Screen          -         HP PrO100
```

i need to produce the following 4 columns that say:
Black Screen happened 3 times in total, 2 times on a DELL DX300 and 1 Time on an HP PRO100.

```
***Problem (Col A)   -  Total Occurrence (Col B) -   Model (Col C)        -  Times (Col D)***    
Black Screen (Col A) -         3 (Col B)         -   DELL DX300 (Col C)   -  2 (Col D)
                                                     HP PRO100 (Col C)    -  1 (Col D)
```

Hope i haven't confused you!

Many thanks!

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, haven't tried something as i am trying to figure out how to approach it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS. Copy all of your models into Column C (removing duplicates before if necessary), and then put this formula in D2.

`=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,C2,$A$2:$A$6,"Black Screen")`

(Pictured)

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh,

The result isn't correct. i should have 45  as a first result and i just get 3.

Comment: Are you sure the range includes all of your cells? (I just went up to $B$6, but I'm sure there are more in your file.)

Comment: Here is a link of the actual data i am trying to work on. 
Sorry for the "Problem" being in Greek.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4OCMZAbT5PJMHRjdm94RXJZMmM

Thanks so much!

Comment: Yeah, so based on your data I adjusted the formula to (for example) 
 `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$489,C2,$A$2:$A$489,"Μήνυμα Βλάβης στην οθόνη")`. Adjusted as needed. It seems to be working.

Comment: Quick question: can i make the last part ("Μήνυμα Βλάβης στην οθόνη") to be retrieved from a cell (e.g. "=G5") which equals "Μήνυμα Βλάβης στην οθόνη"??
Thanks again!

Comment: Absolutely - just make sure not to put it in quotes. So, using the example above, `=COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$489,C2,$A$2:$A$489,G5)`